# In rails it 'thread safe' to create a class instance variable as long as I clear it at the end of the request?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Would it be considered "thread safe" to store a class level instance invariable (i.e. MyClass.foo) as long as I clear it at the end of the request?  For example setting the value in a before_filter and clearing it in an after_filter?

My understanding is if I do not clear it.. it will exist for future requests which I do not want.  But if I set it and clear it.. is that good enough?  Or could two requests overlap and cause a collision and mutated data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably a really bad idea as it might bleed information between requests and sessions. If you need a short-term cache that's thread-safe, you can always spike methods on to the `request` object that's created for you.

If you're trying to push session information down into the global context of a model then you're going against the MVC design pattern. Any information a model needs should be passed in in a well-defined manner, especially as this makes testing orders of magnitude simpler and more reliable.